# Sound::readData of Fmod.dll returns empty array

Tags: c++, mfc

I use Sound::readData of Fmod.dll to get the data out of the mp3 file;

void *pointer1 = new byte[ 4096 ];
unsigned int length;

system -> createSound( filePath, FMOD_OPENONLY | FMOD_ACCURATETIME, NULL, &sound );

sound-> readData( pointer1, 4096, &length );

But all of 4096 byte is 0, does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the FMOD_ACCURATETIME flag probably made it scan to the end of the file so you got an EOF, did you check the error code if there was one?
Remove FMOD_ACCURATETIME or try sound->seekData(0); before the readdata call